# Node js sending multiple requests after 20 secs

Tags: javascript, node.js

My node js app is making multiple http request if there is delay in response of say 20 secs. Below is the sample code for the same.

First I make call to the getAPI function from browser. getApi function calls the getAccessToken API, after receiving the accesstoken I am calling the testApi. Now if there is a delay of 20 secs in response from testApi then getAccessToken Api is getting called again. I don't want to use promise. Can anyone point out what I am missing or doing wrong here?

```
shttp = require('http-https');  

exports.getAPI = function(typeObj, request, response, callback) {
var userConf; //contains info such as port, host, url etc

_this.getAccessToken(function(tokenResponse) {
    var tokenInfo = JSON.parse(tokenResponse);
    var accessToken = JSON.parse(tokenInfo.response);
    accessToken = accessToken.access_token;
   if(accessToken) {
    _this.testApi(userConf,accessToken,function(sjmResponse) {
        callback(sjmResponse);
    }
   } else {
     callback(JSON.stringify({"payLoad":null,"reasonCode":"fail","status":null}));
   }
});
};


exports.getAccessToken = function(cb) {
    var tokenConf;  //contains info such as port, host, url etc
    var httpReq = shttp.request(tokenConf, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            var body = "";
            res.on('data', function (result) {
                body += result;
            });

            res.on('end', function (){
                cb(JSON.stringify({error: '', response: (body)}));
            });
        } else {
            cb(JSON.stringify({error: 'Failed to get user access token '+res.statusCode, response:''}));
        }
    });

    httpReq.on('error', function(e) {
        cb(JSON.stringify({error: 'Failed to get user access token'+e, response:''}));
    });

    httpReq.end();
};


exports.testApi = function(userConf,accessToken,sjmCallback) {
    var userConf; //contains info such as port, host, url etc
    var httpSubmitReq = shttp.request(userConf, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            var body = "";
            res.on('data', function (result) {
                body += result;
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                sjmCallback(body);
            });
        } else {
            sjmCallback(JSON.stringify({"payLoad":null,"reasonCode":"fail","status":null}));

        }
    });

    httpSubmitReq.on('error', function(e) {
        sjmCallback(JSON.stringify({"payLoad":null,"reasonCode":"fail","status":null}));
    });

    httpSubmitReq.end();
};
```

---

```
app.get('/testApi', function (req, res) {
var typeObj = {};
typeObj.apiType= 'testApi';
    try {
        getAPI(JSON.stringify(typeObj), req, res, function(response) {
            res.end(response);
        });
    } catch(err) {
        res.end(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking why `testApi()` does something odd if there's a delay of 20 seconds?  If you're asking why `getAccessToken()` is getting called more than once, then you'll have to show us the code that calls it since that is probably where the problem lies.

Comment: I do notice that you don't seem to have a clean way of communicating back errors from `getAccessToken()`.  You call the callback with an object in all cases, yet the function you pass in, looks for a falsey parameter to the callback which never happens.  Doesn't explain why anything gets called twice, but it does mean an error looks the same as success to your code which is unlikely to be correct.  Specifically, this line `if (accessToken)` will always be `true`.

Comment: @jfriend00, actually I have not posted the complete code here. If you see the response of getAccesToken function,  cb(JSON.stringify({error: '', response: (body)})); I am sending response: body which I parse before if(accessToken) { } something like this 

       `var tokenInfo = JSON.parse(accessToken);

        var accessToken = JSON.parse(accessToken.response);

        accessToken = accessToken.access_token; `

Comment: Well, we can't really help if you don't show the appropriate code, particularly how things are called (which is probably where your problem is).

Comment: @jfriend00, please check now. I have added the route function too which calls the getAPI function

Comment: If possible, can anyone provide a sample code where I need to send an http request. Once I receive response from that request use that response and make another http request.

Comment: At least can anyone tell me if there is anything missing or mistake in the above code?